# Passing a string between Java and javaScript with Rhino

Tags: javascript, java, switch-statement, rhino

I'm trying to pass a Java string to JavaScript using Rhino, and have it recognized as a "native" JavaScript string.

Example:

Java object:

```
public class MyTestObject {
    public Object returnStringValue() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Rhino setup

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javax.script.*;

public class TestRhino{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException {
        // Create my Java Object
        MyTestObject testObject = new MyTestObject();

        // Initiate the JavaScript engine
        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("javascript");
        Compilable compEngine = (Compilable)engine;

        // evaluate my JavaScript file; add my Java object to it
        engine.eval(new java.io.FileReader("MyJavaScriptFile.js"));
        engine.put("testObject", testObject); // this adds my Java Object to Rhino

        // Invoke my javaScript function
        Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;
        Object returnVal = inv.invokeFunction("testFunction");

        // print out the result
        System.out.println(returnVal);
    }
}
```

the JavaScript function (this **cannot** be modified)

```
function testFunction() {
    let myString = testObject.returnStringValue();

    switch (myString)
    {
        case "Hello":
            return "OK";
    }

    return "Not OK";
}
```

Current output: "Not OK".

I think this due to Rhino applying strict switch comparison as the following returns `Switch comparison is strict.`.

```
function testFunction() {
    switch(1) {
        case '1':
            return 'Switch comparison is NOT strict.';
        case 1:
            return 'Switch comparison is strict.';
    }
}
```

Also note that the following function returns `true`

```
function testFunction() {
    let myString = testObject.returnStringValue();
    return myString == "Hello";
}
```

But the following function returns `false`

```
function testFunction() {
    let myString = testObject.returnStringValue();
    return myString === "Hello";
}
```

I cannot modify the JavaScript code, only the Java code, so I am looking for a solution which would make the switch statement work by modifying only the Java code.

As a note, this works well on Nashorn (default JavaScript engine implemented from Java 1.8 onwards), however I have to use Rhino.